# Widget's buttons doesn't work after phone restart

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, boot

Well, I have an desktop widget, and inside there are few buttons. Each button should launch an Activity. Everything goes perfectly, but when I restart phone, widget buttons doesn work anymore. Of course, when I delete widget, and add it again, everything works again. Whats the problem? I implemented it like this:

MANIFEST

```
<receiver android:name=".MyWidget">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        ...
    </intent-filter>
    ...
</receiver>
```

RECEIVER

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

        // in service, due to possible ANR erors
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
        newIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        context.startService(newIntent);
        return;
    }
```

UPDATESERVICE (Its INTENT SERVICE not standard SERVICE)

```
    private boolean update() {
                    ...

            popup.showShort("whoaaa - onUpdate");

            i = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 2, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnSettings, pi);

            i = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
            pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 3, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnAbout, pi);

                   ...
        }
```

Whats best, I can see popup on every update, even after phone is restarted. So its 100% sure that after restart my `receiver` runs its `onUpdate` method, which fires my `UpdateService`(its intent service) and its `update` method runs correctly. So how its possible, that after restart no buttons in my widget react on clicking? Like there are no intents registered (or delivered).

PS: Maybe u will say, i need register receiver for `BOOT_COMPLETED`, but as I know its necessary only when u need to do some special work (for example re-register alarms after rebooting - which is not my case).

Comment: same problem here years later xD

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely can't understand it, but when I add code from `onUpdate` method (in receiver):

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
newIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
context.startService(newIntent);
```

to `onEnabled` it works...But its really hard to understand, because my update method (in UpdateService) was ALWAYS properly fired, i saw popup...

Now its fired twice (from onEnabled and immediately after that from onUpdate) and it works...Who can explain this please? I missed something very very important from docs probably.

EDIT: Correction, it works only sometimes....strange